# I need help doing this double summation in python

Tags: python, math, sum

I'm pretty new in python and I'm having trouble doing this double summation.

[image: Summation]

I already tried using

```
x = sum(sum((math.pow(j, 2) * (k+1)) for k in range(1, M-1)) for j in range(N))
```

and using 2 for loops but nothing seens to work

Comment: You can code a double summation with the help of python list comprehension.

Comment: Your formula specifies a sum over the range j = 1 to 1. Is that right? Because you don't need a sum for that bit: you can just replace j with 1.

Comment: `x = sum(sum(j ** 2 * (k + 1) for k in range(2)) for j in range(1, 2))`

Comment: Remember that in Python, `range()` is exclusive of the end of the range, but in math it includes the end. So you have to add  to the end.

Comment: What are M and N, and how do they relate to the math formula?

Comment: @Barmar, if I interpreted formula correctly, `N` is an upper bound of outer summation and equals `1`, `M` is an upper bound of inner summation and equals `1` as well.

Comment: Then it should be `k in range(0, M+1)`, not `k in range(1, M-1)`. It looks like you were subtracting 1 instead of adding 1.

Comment: .. or just `k in range(M + 1)`, second should be `j in range(1, N + 1)`

Comment: Sorry guys, first time posting here, N and M are user input values

Comment: I uploaded the wrong image, sry. Put the correct one now

Comment: you better declare M,N and describe more about this question as well, then users can easily understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```py
N = int(input("N: "))
M = int(input("M: "))

x = sum(sum(j ** 2 * (k + 1) for k in range(M)) for j in range(1, N + 1))
```

It also can be done with nested `for` loops:

```py
x = 0
for j in range(1, N + 1):  # [1, N]
    for k in range(M):  # [0, M - 1]
        x += j ** 2 * (k + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little math...

```
x = M * (M+1) * N * (N+1) * (2*N+1) // 12
```